# Wpf TreeView Multi Level hierarchy

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I Have this Class

```
 public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Country Parent { get; set; }

    public List<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Country> SubCountries { get; set; }
}
```

Want to view the collection in a TreeView control in multi level hierarchy

Here is the Xaml code

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewTemp"  DataType="TreeViewItem"  ItemsSource="{Binding SubCountries}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>


     <TreeView Name="TreeView_Countries" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewTemp}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="510,14,-510,-14">


 </TreeView>
```

The main countries are perfectly loaded with perfect hierarchy BUT the problem is the the SubCountreis are loaded again with its SubCountries underneath ..
Any Help!!

Comment: I had this from a while ago. Seems like the same problem for the most part.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928476/how-do-i-dynamically-make-user-controls-in-a-hierarchicaldatatemplate-editable-r/27929939#27929939

Comment: Clarify added again. Do Country get correctly materialized?

Comment: @E-Bat yes it does

Comment: @AmrIbrahim could you please explain the problem more clear.  What you expect and what it renders?

Comment: @Gopichandar updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution .. it was very simple actually ...

All I had to do was filtering the items
source collection to caontain only the parent countries

```
TreeView_Countries.ItemsSource = collection.Where(x => x.ParentId == null);
```